# Class inherit other css styling - ng-deep problem

Tags: css, angular, queryselector, ng-deep

I have a problem, a button that belongs to an InfoWindow component. The button isn't created in the HTML part of the code but is called whenever the card component is open. I use this InfoCard in two places of the application, and in each component, I change the position of the button using ::ng-deep, because without it the changes won't be applied. The problem is whenever I change from one page to another, the component child1 inherits the child2 CSS of the button, and the same way when I check child1 first. I thought about adding a class to each button and changing in the CSS the call of classes `.class1.button` and `.class2.button`, but the problem is the button isn't displayed until I click in the showInfo button to display the card, so in typescript the class is displayed none, and I can't add a class to a class with display none.
Any help on how I can solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is rather difficult to understand for me given your description. However, you might take a look at the following [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context). E.g. :host-context can be used to differentiate style application based on the context, e.g. the presence of some class in some ancestor component - assuming you apply some StyleEncapsulation.